# jQuery tablesorter issue in Firefox only - header row disappears after show-hide of rows

Tags: firefox, html-table, show-hide, tablesorter

When the page loads, all the records show. Sorting works great until show-hide is used to filter the rows so only some show. Then the header row--with the arrows for sorting--DISAPPEARS. The problem is only in Firefox. It works great in IE7 and IE8.

I'm using jQuery 1.4.2 from Google.

Code for show-hide

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // show all the rows
    $("#org_status tr").show();

    //find selected filter
    $("#filter_status a").click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $("#org_status tr").hide();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $("." + id).show();
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!-- show-hide "buttons" -->
<p id='filter_status'>Filter by status: 
    <a href='#' id='All'>All</a> 
    <a href='#' id='Active'>Active</a> 
    <a href='#' id='Inactive'>Inactive</a> 
    <a href='#' id='Pending'>Pending</a>
</p>

<!-- table to sort ->
<table id='org_status' class='info_table tablesorter'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class='org-name-col'>Name</th>
      <th class='org-status-col'>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr class='All Active'>
  <td><a href='admin/org_edit.php?org=29'>Foo Net</a></td>
  <td>Active</td>";
</tr>
<tr class='All Inactive'>
  <td><a href='admin/org_edit.php?org=22'>Bar</a></td>
  <td>Active</td>";
</tr>
<tr class='All Pending'>
  <td><a href='admin/org_edit.php?org=11'>
      Bar Foo Very Long Org Name Goes Here</a></td>
  <td>Active</td>";
</tr>
  </tbody>  
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is just an issue for firefox because the header row is first made to hide and the code deosn't show it up later. 
Try changing the code as follows:
**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // show all the rows
    $("#org_status tr").show();

    //find selected filter
    $("#filter_status a").click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $("#org_status tr").hide();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $("." + id).show();
    $(".showAlways").show();
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<p id='filter_status'>Filter by status: 
    <a href='#' id='All'>All</a> 
    <a href='#' id='Active'>Active</a> 
    <a href='#' id='Inactive'>Inactive</a> 
    <a href='#' id='Pending'>Pending</a>
</p>

<table id='org_status' class='info_table tablesorter'>
  <thead>
    <tr  class="showAlways">
      <th class='org-name-col'>Name</th>
      <th class='org-status-col'>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr class='All Active'>
  <td><a href='admin/org_edit.php?org=29'>Foo Net</a></td>
  <td>Active</td>";
</tr>
<tr class='All Inactive'>
  <td><a href='admin/org_edit.php?org=22'>Bar</a></td>
  <td>Active</td>";
</tr>
<tr class='All Pending'>
  <td><a href='admin/org_edit.php?org=11'>
      Bar Foo Very Long Org Name Goes Here</a></td>
  <td>Active</td>";
</tr>
  </tbody>  
</table>
```

Comment: When I started thinking about cross-browser issues, I realized I needed to validate the page and now it works in all browsers. Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that it wasn't only an issue in firefox!